# Java - Insert values from Array of type Float, into a New Array of type float by index

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, floating-point

I have 2 Arrays and an ArrayList

```
float[] a = new float [1000]; // contains 1000 float values

float[] b = new float [1000]; // contains 1000 float values

ArrayList<Float> c = new ArrayList<Float>(); // contains unique list of float values from array a
```

I wish to perform the following

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
      b[c.indexOf(c.get(i)]++; 
}
```

Essentially, i am wanting to go through the length of a, find where the first value from C is found, then insert that into a new array b.

However i am returned with an index out of bound error, or incompatible type error expected float() found int().

I have also experiment with wrappers when defining float, due to primitive types.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Also bracket for `indexOf` isn't closed.

Comment: Isn't `c.indexOf(c.get(i))` equal to `i`?

Comment: @Jivings, it is, as far as c doesn't have duplicate entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here both the arrays a and b are of type float.

by the statement 
**b[c.indexOf(c.get(i)]++;**  you are applying an increment operator which is for int datatypes not float.

So to do what you want you have to typecast the float to integer than you can apply this increment operator.

Comment: I mean to say you have to convert your b array to int.
There is one more thing that you can try is use following 
b[x] = b[x] + 1;   instead of b[x]++.
This way you don't have to worry about type casting.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Float> c = new ArrayList<Float>(); // contains unique list of float values from array a
```

Since it contains only unique entries from `a`, it's length <= a.length. and hence your exception `IndexOutOfBounds`

```
c.get(i)
```

if `i >= c.size()`: it will throw exception.

This is one solution:

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) 
{
    if(i >= c.size())
        break;
    b[c.indexOf(c.get(i)]++;  
}
```

OR, simply

```
for (int i=0; i<c.size(); i++) 
{
    b[c.indexOf(c.get(i)]++;  
}
```

OR, more simply

```
for (int i=0; i<a.length; i++) 
{
    b[i]++;  
}
```

But, what do you want to do with duplicate values in `a` and the remaining indexes?

Answer (score 0):

From your question it looks like you want something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if ( c.contains(a[i]) ) { // when c contains a[i]
       b[i] = a[i];           // insert a[i] into b
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

what if your arraylist c does not have 1000 elements?

how about

```
for (int i=0; i<c.size(); i++) {
      b[c.indexOf(c.get(i)]++; 
}
```

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 256, Size: 256

Comment: please check and see the size of ArrayList c before the for loop